# Check WordPress size on disk

Tags: server, linux

Is there is any plugin or method to check how much wordpress size is on disk.

Let's say I have **two different directories** (abc.com, abc.com/differentPath) on abc.com domain, and in both directories, **separately wordpress** is installed.

Now I want to check how much abc.com and abc.com/differentPath size on disk.

I want to know whole wordpress size including Media, theme, plugins, etc.

Comment: Lets say you have ssh access to a Linux OS variant, by using following command it will display the size of a folder *(lets say WordPress)*: `du -h wordpress` . Want to have a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dashboard-directory-size/) try this one.

Comment: down voted as I find it hard to see how it is remotely related to wordpress development

Comment: @Mark-Kaplun just for you kind info, I am new to here and stackexchange won't allow me to create tags like (wordpress, count, size).  since I don't have enough reputations. Hope you understand and stop down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Why using a plugin for that?

You can set a function to calculate the size of the 2 installations. The size of abc.com will include also the size of the other installation, but then you can subtract the smallest from the largest.

```
$path = ABSPATH;
$size = foldersize($path);


function folderSize ($dir)
{
    $size = 0;
    foreach (glob(rtrim($dir, '/').'/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each) {
        $size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : folderSize($each);
    }
    return $size;
}
```